# Javascript check if bit is set

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a number `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD` and It's position `0x2`, `0x80`.

I want to check if the bit position of the number is active or not.

I don't have much experience with bit operators So sorry for the obvious mistakes I might have made.

```
if ( 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD & 0x2 ) {
    console.log("true");
} else { console.log("false"); }


if ( 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD & 0x80 ) {
    console.log("true");
} else { console.log("false"); }


if ( 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD & 0x40 ) {
    console.log("true");
} else { console.log("false"); }
```

Or

```
if ( (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD & 0x2) != 0 ) {
    console.log("true");
} else { console.log("false"); }


if ( (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD & 0x80) != 0 ) {
    console.log("true");
} else { console.log("false"); }


if ( (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD & 0x40) != 0 ) {
    console.log("true");
} else { console.log("false"); }
```

I tried this, But I get `false` for all, which according to the expected output is false.

Comment: Why the downvote Bruh, If there's anything missing or if I have made a mistake do let me know.

Comment: If you want the `n`th bit of a value `v`, you'd want to logically and `v` with a bitmask like `1 << n`

Comment: @CollinD something like this? `( ( 1 << 0x80 & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD ) != 0 )` (-_-)

Comment: Keep in mind that you numbers are well above than  `0x1fffffffffffff` which is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: @DBellavista Right idea, but `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` isn't relevant. Bitwise ops are done with 32 bit integers, which is a measly `0xffffffff` maximum.

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript is converting numbers to 32bit when you do bitwise operations as stated there: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

> The examples above uses 4 bits unsigned examples. But JavaScript uses
>   32-bit signed numbers. Because of this, in JavaScript, ~ 5 will not
>   return 10. It will return -6. ~00000000000000000000000000000101 will
>   return 11111111111111111111111111111010
>
> Bitwise operators are fully described in the JS Bitwise chapter.

Lets try example, this:

```
console.log(0xff);
console.log(0xff & 0xff);
console.log(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD)
console.log(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD)
```

will have this output:

```
255
255
18446744073709552000
0
```

As you can see, doing `&` with two same number return that number. Because this does not happen for your huge number, it is clear that reason is in conversion.